# List of books for an undergraduate mathematics major student?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I plan on majoring in mathematics at UC Davis and I wanted to know of what list of books I should read and study for my bachelors in mathematics. Any recommendations and list of books experienced mathematicians and math students can suggest to me?

Comment: Perhaps this is controversial, but I think that the single most important book you can read is Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin.

Comment: Ron Larson's Calculus is a pretty easy read since it comes with a free solution manual online. Larson also has a textbook on Linear Algebra. Dummit and Foote will be a good book to read once you've mastered Linear Algebra since it will give you a comprehensive introduction to abstract algebra. However, calculus is NOT representative of what being a math major is all about. Linear Algebra (specifically any exercises that say "proof") will give you a really good idea on *what* being a math major is all about. Thus, take a look at linear algebra and see what you think.

Comment: I vote to close this question in its current state, as it is too broad. Questions on particular subjects, a given problem in a given book or questions for guidelines to get into a given field are - in my opinion - appropriate to ask on MSE. Basically asking for an outline of the entire coursework for a bachelor degree - on the other hand - is not.

Comment: I'd also say that "Methods of Real Analysis" by Goldberg is also a really nice textbook on the introduction to analysis. Basically, you might ask "What is analysis?" Analysis is a *reboot* of calculus where you go back to the VERY beginning of math and prove some elementary results to build up to be able to prove elementary results of calculus (limits, derivatives, etc.). It's *much* much much different from *doing* calculus. I've never read Rudin, but as a graduate student, many of my textbooks I use *now* cross-reference it quite a bit, showing its importance and relevance in the math world.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4rzbfl/good_approach_to_self_studying_as_a_rising_math/

Answer (score 3):

$$\text{Knuth - Concrete Math}$$

Comment: why? $\quad\quad$

Comment: @tired Because our professor of Analysis 1 told us, at the very first month of the first year of University, told us to buy it and study it, as a good extra of the program. And since it does contain treasures and things people must know, I give the same advice my professor gave us then.